# Nested document searches in Solr complex parentFilter syntax

Tags: solr, nested, parent-child

We are adding nested documents to our Solr index.  For this purpose, we've added a solr_record_type field to each record, but there will be an interval while we are updating the index where the original documents will have null in this field.  We would like to treat all of the original documents as root documents.

In our Solr index, solr_record_type equals 1 and the child types are represented by 2-4.  So, in order to get backwards compatibility with what is currently returned by queries, I added this fq parameter:

```
-solr_record_type:[2 TO 4]
```

However, I am having trouble composing the parentFilter in the [`child`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/transforming-result-documents.html) transformer. For the `fl` field I've tried:

```
*,[child parentFilter="-solr_record_type:[2 TO 4]"]
```

This doesn't work because it then omits the `_childDocuments_` section from the results for some reason.  I don't know why.  I need some way to specify that the parent filter is either "null or 1" or "anything but 2, 3, and 4".  How can I do this?

I was unable to find a definitive reference for syntax for the parentFilter, only very simple examples.

Comment: A negative query usually have to be prepended by `*:*` to indicate what you're subtracting from (the regular query parsers usually does this automagically for you if it's a pure negative query). See if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A negative query needs to be prefixed with what it's going to remove the documents from. Think of it as the intersection between the two sets, and if you only have the set which are "these documents should be removed", you have nothing to remove them from.

The regular query parser (and the edismax handlers) append the set of all documents, `*:*` automagically in front of negative queries for you, so it appears to work - until you start with longer `AND` and `OR` statements involving negative queries, where you suddenly need to prefix `*:*` as well.

The same is the case in the `parentFilter` syntax - there is no inherent set of all documents automagically prefixed internally, so if you have a negative query, you'll have to add it yourself.

```
*,[child parentFilter="*:* -solr_record_type:[2 TO 4]"]
```